# pyautogui.typewrite не работает русский

Tags: python

Библиотека PyAutoGUI Питон.

```
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')    # вводит на английском.  
pyautogui.typewrite('Привет мир!')     # на русском не вводит.
```

Kак сделать ввод на русском?

Answer (score 1):

`typewrite()` - это симуляция нажатия клавиш. Библиотека знает только клавиши на английском языке. [Документация](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys).

Соответственно выход: написать функцию, которая переведет строку на русском в английскую раскладку клавиатуры и вернет полученное как аргумент `typewrite()`.
Дальше следите, чтобы в том поле, куда выводятся нажатия, стоял СИСТЕМНЫЙ русский язык.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам не нужно менять текст то, напишите русский текст , так будто забыли сменить раскладку с английской.
К примеру , чтобы напечатать "Привет" нужно передать "Ghbdtn",и еще,при выполнении скрипта поставьте русскую раскладку клавиатуры

Answer (score 1):

Приведём пример:

- `pg.hotkey("shift", "alt")` меняет язык на Английский
- `pg.typewrite("ghbdtn", 0.5)` сам текст (русский) придётся писать, например, `привет`, а написать надо `ghbdtn` (это слово `привет` в английской раскладке)

Сам код:

```
pg.hotkey("shift", "alt")
pg.typewrite("ghbdtn", 0.5)
pg.hotkey("shift", "alt")
```