# Посоветуйте модуль для ввода текста (Python) (что-то вроде pyautogui)

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, модули, pyautogui

Посоветуйте модуль для *ввода текста* (**Python**)
Работал с **pyautogui**

```
pyautogui.write('Текст')
```

но этот модуль не может вводить **русские** буквы. Есть ли какой-то другой? спасибо

Comment: можно и на pyautogui. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151865/input-unicode-string-with-pyautogui ; https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952420/pyautogui-typewrite-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Спасибо большое