# pyautogui проблема с кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я думаю объяснять проблему с кириллицей и pyautogui не надо
Какой можете посоветовать модуль или код для нажатия одной клавиши просто в приложении нужно открыть чат
А естественно если это делать через pyautogui то если запускать на русской раскладке то скрипт просто не работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [pyautogui.typewrite не работает русский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952420/pyautogui-typewrite-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9)