# как сделать русский текст? python

Tags: python, pyautogui

код должен брать по строке с текстового документа(two.txt), текст на русском,
и писать его в telegram чат.
но он выдавал ошибку пока не дописал (encoding='utf-8') но после этого он не выводил сам текст а лишь символы и цифры, помогите пожалуйста

код :

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
a = open("Two.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
for Line in a:
  pyautogui.typewrite(Line)
  pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Перекодируйте текстовый файл с помощью блокнота на UTF-8 (Файл -> Сохранить как, слева от кнопки "сохранить" будет выбор кодировки (метод для Windows)).

Comment: увы не помогло, всё также как и было раньше

Comment: Это проблема на уровне библиотеки pyautogui (к сожалению я её не знаю), файл открывается нормально. Похожий вопрос с возможным решением: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952420/pyautogui-typewrite-не-работает-русский]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку codecs:

```py
import pyautogui, time
import codecs
time.sleep(5)
with codecs.open("Two.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        pyautogui.typewrite(Line)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Comment: увы не помогло, также пишет только символы и цифры